# Objects and the "in" keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var hash = { 'foo': 'foo!' }

console.log('foo' in hash); // 'true'
```

What is actually going on behind the scenes when `'foo' in hash` is evaluated? Is a hash-table data structure being used, with a hash function being used to address the data 'buckets' (i.e. the properties in the object `hash`)?

Comment: Yes, objects are hash tables.

Comment: It's implementation-dependent. See the duplicate question.